# Missing write access when installing Vue CLI

Tags: npm, vue-cli

For some reason I cannot run the vue cli and trying to reinstall using:

```
npm install -g @vue/cli
```

I get a string of

```
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/@apollographql/graphql-playground-html
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/semver
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/@babel/helper-plugin-utils
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/@babel/parser
```

And then ending with

```
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/@apollographql/graphql-playground-html
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/@apollographql/graphql-playground-html'
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/@apollographql/graphql-playground-html'
npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EACCES: permission denied, access \'/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/@apollographql/graphql-playground-html\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/node_modules/@apollographql/graphql-playground-html' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.
```

I have tried changing the permissions of /usr/local/lib/node_modules and then changed the group to "staff" (which is the same as Python also in /lib.  I don't think I can uninstall node without some serious problems everywhere I use that.  Stuck and not sure how to install or get vue cli running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just had the same issue, but solved it by adding "sudo" before it.

So, the new line would instead look like;

```
sudo npm install -g @vue/cli
```

Comment: I know this sounds dumb, I had read somewhere that I SHOULD NOT USE SUDO but for the life of my I cannot remember why or where I read it.  Seems so obvious I feel stupid.  Thanks @KJParker

Comment: My pleasure! 

I too have read that using sudo is a bad idea, I cannot remember why, and there is a better way around it but, when ina  pinch it sure is handy! :D